# Pulling out "text" from JSON

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a google app script that works with telegram. The user will key in their unique 4 digit code and it will run against my array. i have most of the stuff working. I'm currently stuck getting my code to match the users input.

from the JSON below. i am only able to extract the first result in my syntax.

for example extracting the chatid

```
var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)
var id = contents.message.from.id
```

But what i am trying to extract is the "Welcome" from the text portion of the 2nd response.

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "update_id": 11111111,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 412,
        "from": {
          "id": 22222222,
          "is_bot": false,
          "first_name": "don",
          "username": "king",
          "language_code": "en"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 333333333,
          "first_name": "Don",
          "username": "king",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1600865179,
        "text": "Test"
      }
    },
    {
      "update_id": 111111111,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 413,
        "from": {
          "id": 1111111111,
          "is_bot": false,
          "first_name": "Don",
          "username": "king",
          "language_code": "en"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 44444444,
          "first_name": "don",
          "username": "king",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1600865186,
        "text": "Welcome"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the main part of my script that has difficulty. I was able to log and confirm it works and generates the values and array i need. However when i send an input to telegram it stops at "Please Wait".

```html
function doPost(e){
    var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    var id = contents.message.from.id;
    sendMessage(id, "Please wait");
    var userInput = contents.result[1].message.text;
    var ssId = "XXXX";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var idArr = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
    idArr = idArr.map(row => row[0]);
    var idIndex = idArr.indexOf(userInput);
     if(userinput == idArr){
        let rowNumber = idIndex + 3;
        let colNumber = 4; //col D
        var dateNow = new Date;
        sheet.getRange(rowNumber, colNumber).setValue(dateNow);
        sendMessage(id, "You have successfully registered");
        
    }
    else{
        
sendMessage(id, "user not found");

    }
  
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to capture all values in an array? Examine them independently? Please revise to clarify.

Comment: I think it would be `contents.result[1].text`

Comment: @cooper8 I think this is what I'm looking for. I couldn't get the correct syntax to pull the text. Will try this shortly to see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
console.log(contents.result[1].message.text)}
```

```js
  
 contents= {
  "ok": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "update_id": 11111111,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 412,
        "from": {
          "id": 22222222,
          "is_bot": false,
          "first_name": "don",
          "username": "king",
          "language_code": "en"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 333333333,
          "first_name": "Don",
          "username": "king",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1600865179,
        "text": "Test"
      }
    },
    {
      "update_id": 111111111,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 413,
        "from": {
          "id": 1111111111,
          "is_bot": false,
          "first_name": "Don",
          "username": "king",
          "language_code": "en"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 44444444,
          "first_name": "don",
          "username": "king",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1600865186,
        "text": "Welcome"
      }
    }
  ]
}
 
 
 console.log(contents.result[1].message.text)
```

Comment: Hi Marios thanks for the help..... its still not working but i believe the syntax you provided was correct. i think it maybe other parts of my code that i may have gotten wrong. trying to add it into my main post

Comment: the contents.result syntax you provided works! i think its the later part of my code. But one problem solved. Thanks for teaching me something new. Initially i could not figure out the "result[1]" portion and how to phrase it in my syntax

Answer (score 2):

The result inside that JSON is an array so you could try loop it to get the data. try this....

```js
  var yourJSON = {
  ok: true,
  result: [
    {
      update_id: 11111111,
      message: {
        message_id: 412,
        from: {
          id: 22222222,
          is_bot: false,
          first_name: "don",
          username: "king",
          language_code: "en",
        },
        chat: {
          id: 333333333,
          first_name: "Don",
          username: "king",
          type: "private",
        },
        date: 1600865179,
        text: "Test",
      },
    },
    {
      update_id: 111111111,
      message: {
        message_id: 413,
        from: {
          id: 1111111111,
          is_bot: false,
          first_name: "Don",
          username: "king",
          language_code: "en",
        },
        chat: {
          id: 44444444,
          first_name: "don",
          username: "king",
          type: "private",
        },
        date: 1600865186,
        text: "Welcome",
      },
    },
  ],
};

for (var x in yourJSON.result) {  // Example 1
  var fromId = yourJSON.result[x].message.from.id;
  if (fromId == 1111111111) {  // condition to get the data you want
    console.log(yourJSON.result[x].message.text); // Welcome extraction
  }
}

yourJSON.result.map((data) => { // Example 2
  var fromId = data.message.from.id;
  if (fromId == 1111111111) {   // condition to get the data you want
    console.log(yourJSON.result[x].message.text); // Welcome extraction
  }
});
```